# Body deleted after route - OSB

Tags: osb

I am calling to Business service in route. The Business is based on XML messaging. 
Sometimes after a route calling I receiving the following error:

> "ErrorBEA-382030 Failure while unmarshalling message: Failed to parse
>   XML text "

and the body is deleted.
I can't change the type of messaging from XML. Is there is other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Check the response coming from the Provider service. The XML being sent is not proper. Try to run Business Service directly.